# One user managing several profiles

Tags: 7, views, users

User type - manager
For example he is Manager and has 4 bands he is manager of.

Manager can create several profiles types (like myspace profiles).
Manager creates bio, gallerys, videos etc... 
So lets say he has 4 bands with all basic data on each profile.
Biography for band A (bio, galleries, videos)
Biography for band B (bio, galleries, videos)
Biography for band C (bio, galleries, videos)
Biography for band D (bio, galleries, videos)

Manager wants to upload picture gallery from last concert from BAND B.
How can he tell drupal that images he is uploading right now should go "Gallery" of band B ?

Comment: An obvious solution would be 'Upload the images to the corresponding galley'. If each gallery is placed logically under each band, or somehow referenced to a band, then here is no problem there.

Comment: Yes, thats obvious, but how ?

Comment: It's not clear from your question, how bands and galleries are implemented and related now. One usual way is to reference the parent node to the gallery through the entity reference field. If it's your choice, you can add an entity reference to galleries, and reference parent nodes there.

Comment: Think of galleries as Facebook gallery. Its easy that each band create several of them. But i have manager account type where one person can manager several profiles. Creating basic profile page (for example biography) for each band by manager is easy, but when i move onto creating several galleries for all bands managed by one user i have a problem in telling Drupal which gallery goes on page of each band.

Comment: Add to gallery content type an entity reference field. Make that field referencing band content type only in field settings. Make it checkboxes widget. You can actually create a view and make it's items selectable.